# Find a circle in which the integral sea different from zero

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

My function is $z^{2} \hat z^{3}$
I don't know if this can be:
Taking the radio circle 2
\begin{equation}
\int z^{2} \hat z^{3} dx  = \int \frac{64}{z} dx  
\end{equation}
This because $z \hat z= |z|^2 = 4$ but this happens twice, so $z \hat z z \hat z= |z|^2 = 16$ y then there is a $\hat z$ without $z$ so $z \hat z = 4 \rightarrow  \hat z = \frac{4}{z}$ 
but I do not know if this is valid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, $z^2\bar z^3=(z\bar z)^2\bar z=|z|^4\bar z$ so using the unit circle $\gamma=e^{it}$ gives
$$ \int_{\gamma}|z|^4\bar z dz=\int_0^{2\pi} e^{-it}ie^{it}dt=2\pi i$$

Comment: I guess @JazminJones mentioned "radius of circle being 2". So if thats the case $\gamma=2e^{it}$ and the integral evaluates to $32\pi i$.

Comment: $32\cdot2\pi i$ not $32\pi i$.

Comment: can you explain the equality in more detail please

Comment: @JazminJones which one?

Comment: Forget it thanks haha

Answer (score 0):

In your case the integrand is

$$(\rho e^{i\theta})^2(\rho e^{-i\theta})^3de^{i\theta}=2^5e^{-i\theta}de^{i\theta}$$ giving the integral

$$\left.32i\right|_0^{2\pi}.$$